# How to set up proxychains correctly?

Tags: curl, proxy, http-proxy, proxychains

I work under corporate proxy, so I can connect to specific urls using curl like this:

just for example it is `curl` to Telegram Bot API:

```
curl --request GET 'https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/getMe' -x '192.168.155.148:9090' -U 'ProxyLogin:ProxyPassword'
```

It works as expected.
Now I use [proxychains4](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) to set proxy settings globally (for example, for using `telnet` because it has no proxy option).

My `/etc/proxychains.conf`:

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
[ProxyList]
http    192.168.155.148   9090 ProxyLogin ProxyPassword
```

And now I'm trying this:

```
proxychains4 curl --request GET 'https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/getMe' -v
```

Getting error:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf [proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/libproxychains4.so [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16 Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
* Could not resolve host: api.telegram.org
* Closing connection 0 curl: (6) getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

This is the save error as I use `curl` without -x and -U!
So looks like `proxychains4` ignores proxy and password from config!

**How to call proxychains4 correctly?**